# React app deployed to heroku successfully but state is not updating

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have a react app that uses a Node backend to communicate with a CosmicJS appointment Scheduler, deployed using Heroku. Everything loads fine, but I am facing a major issue:

The appointment scheduler is still tracking changes from localhost, i.e. I have added code to block filled slots and dates, but the deployed version is not tracking these changes, only after I restart localhost and fill said slots, does the deployed version show these changes. I have searched for hardcoded localhost, but there were alternatives for production. There are no related errors in the logs.

Desired behaviors: changes made on the deployed app should reflect on the deployed version, and not only in localhost.

I have added the logs from heroku, and I can see that the host is not localhost...I am at a loss at what else to try.

Here is part of my package.json:

```
"version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x",
    "npm": "6.14.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

```
2020-11-15T20:14:39.846723+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mPOST /api/appointments [32m200[0m 688.890 ms - 17[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:39.974220+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET / [36m304[0m 0.710 ms - -[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:39.973138+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=bb79006f-cadc-472d-b0d0-ea420d5a105a fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:39.851778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/appointments" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=1a8f60db-7cc2-4399-a910-4b1eb7323662 fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=693ms status=200 bytes=256 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:40.125957+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/bundle.js" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=4a994db7-1803-400d-af48-9fb2e5d3f9cf fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:40.122394+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /bundle.js [36m304[0m 0.541 ms - -[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:40.436762+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/bundle.map.js" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=bd505bb0-6bac-45e9-8e50-24627ee1a7bc fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=272 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:40.437734+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /bundle.map.js [36m304[0m 0.543 ms - -[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:40.555878+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /api/appointments [32m200[0m 10.989 ms - 877[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:40.555417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/appointments" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=f09f39cd-415b-45d3-a5b9-eb13ec8f69f1 fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=1118 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:40.800303+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'metadata' of undefined
2020-11-15T20:14:40.800304+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/server.js:92:34
2020-11-15T20:14:40.800305+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/cosmicjs/index.js:92:16
2020-11-15T20:14:40.800305+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-11-15T20:14:40.800395+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
2020-11-15T20:14:41.196652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=f34e7212-2359-475a-9b9b-626c4dc3f393 fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=302 bytes=244 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:41.196004+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /favicon.ico [36m302[0m 0.731 ms - 23[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:41.225031+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET / [32m200[0m 0.725 ms - 530[0m
2020-11-15T20:14:41.225348+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=c9a3adef-8221-4f98-a85f-dd68cc4a553b fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=850 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:55.007158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/config" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=0921b397-a979-4373-9667-6472f19427ab fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30003ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:14:55.010286+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /api/config [0m-[0m - ms - -[0m
2020-11-15T20:15:10.789420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/config" host=ancient-thicket-51544.herokuapp.com request_id=506e106e-5dcf-454c-ada9-972644f2a1ed fwd="72.70.63.16" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-11-15T20:15:10.794416+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mGET /api/config [0m-[0m - ms - -[0m
```

Comment: first Run your project in local with npm run watch thne open new cmd and  pushed your code

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it had nothing to do with heroku but the way that I deployed the app...I ended up using CosmicJS's deploy option to heroku, and that fixed my issue.